# How to do a HTTP GET in coffeescript to get a JSON from a REST API

Tags: javascript, json, http, coffeescript, request

I'm looking for a simple way to fetch a REST API in Coffeescript and get a json. I'm using the [request library](https://github.com/request/request). When I do that, nothing happen, no error.

```
request = require 'request'

resp = ""
request.get {uri:'https://api.service.co/search?query=paris', json : true}, (err, r, body) -> resp = body
console.log "BODY: " + resp
```

What do I do wrong? Do you know a better way to get a json from a REST api in coffeescript? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect your issue is that `request.get` executes asynchronously, so by the time it hits the `console.log` statement, resp is always `""`.

Try this:

```
request = require 'request'

resp = ""
request.get {uri:'https://api.service.co/search?query=paris', json : true}, (err, r, body) ->
  resp = body
  console.log "BODY: " + resp
```

Comment: I don't see any white space in front of your `console.log` statement. CoffeeScript has significant whitespace, so adding indentation introduces a new block.

Comment: OK thanks now I get that 
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Comment: From there you may wish to get the String value of those objects using `JSON.stringify` on your `resp` Array.

Comment: Then I used JSON.stringify to convert JSON to string and I see my JSON on the console. Thx for your help

Comment: There is no "require" in the browser. The code fails with undefined.